# A smart young driver

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Picked up my brush, walked on the lawn
>   with lively pace at crack of dawn.
>   A smart young driver, headlamps on,
>   some lucent colours I have drawn.

How would you describe me?

Hint:

> My brush has a specific shape.

Hint #2:

> My headlights are extremely luminous.

Comment: Maybe you're 'Drunk'?  I assume we're looking for an adjective...

Comment: @BrentHackers That would be at odds with "smart", no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would describe you as

> bright

Picked up my brush, walked on the lawn, with lively pace at crack of dawn.

> Bright is a [brush shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paintbrush#Artist's_brush_shapes)  which is short with a flat tapering bristle head.
>
>  On a lawn (green) may refer to [bright green](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bright_green) environmentalism based on the belief that technology and social innovation provides the best path for sustainable development.
>  Poetically Maya Angelou’s Caged Bird has the words 'on a dawn bright lawn'.
>
>  [Bright](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bright) meaning lively, it's bright at dawn, and the idiom [bright and early](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bright_and_early).

A smart young driver, headlamps on, some lucent colours I have drawn.

> Bright meaning smart and a [bright young thing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bright_young_thing).
>  A driver with headlamps on refers to brights - the high-intensity beam of vehicle headlamps.
>  Bright meaning luminous, lucent colours.

Comment: Nice job! I was ready to give up hope of this being solved.

Answer (score 8):

Are you:

> A **line-marking cart**? For painting the lines on a playing field?

Picked up my brush, walked on the lawn

> Line marking equipment uses a brush to paint the lines onto the grass.

with lively pace at crack of dawn.

> Carts allow the painting to be done faster than manually painting the lines, and this work is often done early in the morning before a playing field may be used.

A smart young driver, headlamps on,

> I haven't seen carts with headlamps but perhaps they exist? Or maybe this refers to the *floodlights* on a playing field?

some lucent colours I have drawn.

> Normally playing field lines are drawn in lucent, or light reflective colours such as white or yellow.

Comment: This actually works really well. The intended answer is a bit less literal and more wordplayey (is that a word?)

Comment: @jafe "wordplayey" is a word to me :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> A Firefly?

Picked up my brush, walked on the lawn

> Fireflies have a brush-like backside

with lively pace at crack of dawn.

> You can spot fireflies flying around until morning

A smart young driver, headlamps on,

> They look like flying headlights

some lucent colours I have drawn.

> If you look at time-lapses, you can see drawn lines in lucent colors